# Whether Browser Understand the View State of Html Page

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

View State is encrypted in HTML Page so My Question is Whether Browser Understand the View State of Html Page or it is Understand by Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is done by the server. It saves the state for each user/browser. The browser can only see something like the session ID in php (in some hidden fields and/or cookie)

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx